# How can I receive realm change listener notifications after Activity.onStop()?

Tags: android, realm

I want to use realm change listener to trigger notifications in my android app. My problem is that no listeners are triggered when the app is in the background or after Activity.onStop() is triggered. Is there any way to continue receiving change listeners while the app is in the background?

Comment: You should be able to get them if you don't remove change listeners and you don't close Realm in onStop...

Comment: I don't close realm when closing an activity. I created a singleton manager class where I keep an instance of realm and use that in several activities in the app. I only close realm on my application's onTerminate(). Does realm have an auto-close somewhere?

Comment: No, in that case you should be fine. But you must make sure RealmResults is kept as field reference.